# How to substitute host name in Sed Command UNIX

Tags: unix, sed

I want to input a line using SED at the line number 16 the line is 
-javaagent:/prod/msp/domains/dynamicapp_domains/AppDynamic/AppAgent/ver4.1.4.3/javaagent.jar  -Dprobe.id=10.204.198.1_msp_dynamicapp_tomcat_01 -Dprobe.group=10.204.198.1T";

I have used:

```
HOST=$(hostname)

sed -i '16iPROBE_OPTS="-javaagent:/prod/msp/domains/dynamicapp_domains/AppDynamic/AppAgent/ver4.1.4.3/javaagent.jar -Dprobe.id=$HOST_msp_dynamicapp_tomcat_01 -Dprobe.group=$HOST";' startup.sh
```

but is inserts `$HOST` AS it is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the whole string is enclosed by single quotes. So the $ is escaped. You may close the single quote, enclose `$HOST` in double quotes and open the single quote again.

So try this

```
sed -i '16iPROBE_OPTS="-javaagent:/prod/msp/domains/dynamicapp_domains /AppDynamic/AppAgent/ver4.1.4.3/javaagent.jar -Dprobe.id='"$HOST"'_msp_dynamicapp_tomcat_01 -Dprobe.group=$HOST";' startup.sh
```

The double quote around `$HOST` is not vital if `HOST` not contains space

One more comment: Using `$HOST_msp_dynamic...` can cause a difficult to find bug. This refers to an environment variable `HOST_msp_dynamic...` as `_` is a environment variable character. Use `${HOST}_msp_dynamic...` instead.